# Preventing HTTP access to the servers of Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a system running on Amazon's Beanstalk.
We would like to limit access to the server to HTTPS only.
When blocking HTTP on the environment settings - it prevents accessing through the beanstalk DNS.
However, if someone knows the public IP (or name) of any of the servers - he can access them directly through HTTP. It seems that the LB forwards the requests to port 80, so we can not change the security group and remove port 80.
Is there a simple way, to limit HTTP access to be only from the LB?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this through [EC2 Security Groups](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html), which is an Elastic Beanstalk environment property.

By default this allows connections to port 80 from any IP address, but you could remove that rule or replace it with your own IP address (for testing purposes).

Failing that, you could reroute all HTTP traffic to HTTPS at the application level or simply test the CGI property *server_port_secure* and refuse to answer.

Comment: Amazon is using CloudWatch for monitoring the servers, using HTTP. If the monitoring fails - the server is terminated and a new one is started.
Amazon does not provide the IP range where CloudWatch requests is coming from, which means that we can not set the security group to include only CloudWatch. We need to provide access to any IP, which is what we try to prevent.
The servers themselves does not handle HTTPS (it is handled by the LB), so routing all the traffic to HTTPS will create a loop, where the server forwards HTTPS requests to the servers as HTTP, and the servers send them back.

Comment: In my experience, if the health check has never passed, it will not terminate any server instances to try and get it working again, but this doesn't seem to be documented. Alternatively, you may be able to get HTTPS or plain TCP working using the strings HTTPS:443 and TCP:80 as the health check address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need http/80 to be open for health-check to work. The option for you is to redirect all the other requests (except the health check URL) to use https - This way though the port is open, you "dont serve any data in an insecure way".

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

1 - set the Security Group Policy that allows access on port 80 from the Load Balancer only. IMPORTANT!!! Do not use the Load balancer IP in the instances' security group. Use the Load balancer security group ID instead.

2 - remove the public IPs from the instances. You should be good if all your EC2 instances have a private IPs and the ELB has a public IP.